# Using the Visitor Pattern with JavaCC and JJtree

Tags: java, javacc, visitor-pattern

I wrote a scanner and parser using JavaCC and JJtree that generates an abstract syntax tree, and then I wrote a PrintVisitor class with a Visitor object for each node in the tree. However, after running the jjt file through JJtree and JavaCC, the Java compiler gave me this error:

```
PrintVisitor.java:1: error: PrintVisitor is not abstract and does not override
abstract method visit(Command, Object) in GrammarVisitor
```

The reader will note that only one visitor object caused this error, even though I had many other visitor objects implemented in the exact same way for the other nodes in the tree. Why does only

```
visit(Command, Object)
```

cause an error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: The  `PrintVisitor1.java` file that you linked to does not have the error you describe. If you still have an error, I'd suggest deleting all generated files and rerunning JJT and JavaCC.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me what problem you want to fix. In Java, if a method is declared in an interface, it must be be implemented in any nonabstract class that claims to implement that interface. If you don't understand why that is, read any tutorial on interfaces in Java. However, I suspect there is more to it than that.

Comment: Well, I am loathe to admit it because it makes me appear quite useless at debugging and rather stupid, but you are right--the files work perfectly fine after having regenerated them. What really gets me is that I made a dedicated directory for the generated files and cleaned them out every time I made changes. I know, based on my nonexistent problem, that it looks like I haven't done any of my own work, but I really did try everything before posting here. Oh well. Thanks for looking at my work, and my apologies for not really having a problem in the first place. :/

Comment: No problem.  Just a further comment: The visitor pattern is not a good match for your printing task, as every method is the same. You might be better off not using a visitor (i.e. just use a simple recursive method  and/or setting `multi` to `false`.  Of course you may have other reasons for wanting to use `multi = true` and you may be intending to make the printing task more complex in the future.

Comment: As it currently stands, you are right, but my intention is to use the visitor pattern (with some additional code embedded in the grammar itself) to implement scoped symbol tables for variables, perform type checking, and, ultimately, to generate linear code to be fed into an optimizer and compiler backend. I wanted to start out with something simple to make sure that the visitor interface itself was working before complicating it further. Would you agree that the visitor pattern is probably the best way to implement this, or is this there an alternate option that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Sure, the visitor pattern sounds right for your problem. Design patterns often favour one axis of change over others. The visitor pattern works well when the AST structure is fairly stable (i.e. is fixed near the start of development), but the set of operations on them is likely to vary over development time.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the problem stems from using previously generated files from JJtree and JavaCC after changes have been made to the original jjt file and/or to the PrintVisitor class. Thanks to @Theodore Norvell for pointing this out.

As the JJtree Reference Documentation, found [here](https://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html), says,

> > JJTree provides some basic support for the visitor design pattern. If the VISITOR option is set to true JJTree will insert an jjtAccept()
> >     method into all of the node classes it generates, and also generate a
> >     visitor interface that can be implemented and passed to the nodes to
> >     accept.
>
> The name of the visitor interface is constructed by appending Visitor
>   to the name of the parser. The interface is regenerated every time
>   that JJTree is run, so that it accurately represents the set of nodes
>   used by the parser. This will cause compile time errors if the
>   implementation class has not been updated for the new nodes.

To avoid problems like mine, I recommend creating a completely new directory containing only the .jjt file and the Visitor class, and then running JJtree and JavaCC on those. As I learned, it is suprisingly easy to miss deleting one or two old files, and then nothing works correctly.